# Magento 2 How to access built-in Google Analytics javascript object?

Tags: magento2

I want to add custom analytics events to my frontend in Magento 2.2.

I have a Magento 2.2 module with javascript that looks like this:

```js
define([
        "jquery",
    ], function ($) {
        return function (config, element) {
            console.log(ga);
            debugger
}});
```

The client is using the built-in GA support. 
I've tried just accessing ga as above, but it's null.
I've tried accessing window.ga as well but it is also null.
I've tried adding a 100 second timer to give it time to load, but ga and window.ga are both still null.

How do I access the js object to do things in real time?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I have to define it for this usage.

```
define([
        "jquery",
    ], function ($) {
        return function (config, element) {

            (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
                (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
                m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
            })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

            debugger
            // ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
            // ga('send', 'pageview');
```